# AngularJS ng-repeat is not looping through array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to build a loop with ng-repeat but can't iterate over an array of objects. It seems like the loop is not running at all.

I started a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/a2xhzbfm/1/

Below is an example of data (`$scope.postData`) that I'm working with:

```
[
    {
        "Title" : "Test1",
        "Content" : "<div class=\"ExternalClass53DA82296DEE49898B93B8E59F9074BD\"><p>This is a test post.​</p></div>",
        "ImagePath" : "url",
        "Text" : "Apple",
        "Link" : "http://www.apple.com/",
        "Created" : "/Date(1436889599000)/"
    }, {
        "Title" : "Test2",
        "Content" : "<div class=\"ExternalClass53DA82296DEE49898B93B8E59F9074BD\"><p>This is a test post.​</p></div>",
        "ImagePath" : "url2",
        "Text" : "Apple2",
        "Link" : "http://www.apple.com/",
        "Created" : "/Date(1436889599000)/"
    }
]
```

In the JS I'm calling an api that returns a JSON and then storing that in `$scope.postData` variable.

```
var app = angular.module('blogApp',[]);
app.controller('blogController', function($scope){
    console.log('Angular is go!');
    $scope.postData;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'someURL',
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            $scope.postData = data.d.results;
            console.log($scope.postData);


        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data.responseJSON.error);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is what I have for HTML so far. I'll add more divs once I can get the data to print.

```
<body ng-app="blogApp">
    <div ng-controller="blogController" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div ng-repeat="post in postData">
                <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in post">
                    {{key}}:{{val}}There has to be something else!!!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems to work just fine. [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/febojelaro/1/edit?html,js,output). Maybe you need to add `$scope.apply()` in your AJAX `success` callback since you aren't using Angular's implementation of AJAX. [Reference](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching your Ajax call to Angular's own [$http function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) like so:

```
$http.get('someURL', {
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    }
}).success(function(data) {
    $scope.postData = data.d.results;
    console.log($scope.postData);
});
```

It's always recommended to use Angular's built in functions unless you need to use external libraries for cases where these functions aren't enough.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're using jQuery for the Ajax.  Angular doesn't know that you changed `$scope.postData`.  If you use Angular's own Ajax service, [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), it will automatically handle updating the view after you make changes to `$scope`.  But since Angular doesn't have any control over jQuery, there's no way for it to detect the update.

The right way to fix this is to use `$http`, but a wrong way that should work is to call `$scope.$apply()` in your success callback right after you modify `$scope.postData`.

Answer (score 0):

1 ) First you need to update version of AngularJS

2 ) You have a misprint not **in post** but **postData**

check it:

```
 <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in postData">
    {{key}}:{{val}}There has to be something else!!!
 </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/STEVER/a2xhzbfm/3/

Comment: That's not a misprint.  OP is iterating through each object in `postData` and then through each key/value in the object.

Comment: Stever thanks for the note! Will keep that mind, but I think I just had to use $http method for calling the api